# AWS Cloudwatch Logs - Require Multiple Log Groups in single S3 Export Log Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to run multiple export logs to s3 jobs for my log groups in cloudwatch, but it is throwing **LimitExceededException** Error.

Is there a way to include multiple log groups in a single S3 Export log Job??

Comment: Not sure, is the message like "you can run only one export task per time" showing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, You can't export multiple log groups to s3 because each aws account can only have one active export task at a time. So, When exporting multiple log groups, need to wait for each task to finish.
[CreateExportTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateExportTask.html)

In an alternative plan, you can automate the multiple export tasks by using Step Functions.
By using the state machine's wait type, you can wait for the export process to complete and then process the next export task when the process is complete.